# Why does tracMsg not work?

Tags: haskell, hxt

I've seen on HXT library that there is two functions for texting message on the prompt of my terminal which are :

```
withTraceLevel
```

and

```
traceMsg
```

The first function "withTraceLevel" works like a charm, but the second function doesn't work on my code, am i missing something ?

Example of my code :

```
procIntersection = proc it -> do
            set1 <- (getChildren >>> withTraceLevel 5 traceTree >>> traceMsg 1 "*********************************") -< it
            returnA -< Intersection { setI1 = OWLNothing, setI2 = OWLNothing{--set2--} }
```

Output :

```
content of:
============


---XTag "rdf:Description"

   |   "rdf:about"="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#Body"

content of:

============


---XTag "owl:Restriction"

    |

    +---XTag "owl:onProperty"
    |   |   "rdf:resource"="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#shutter-speed"
    |
    +---XTag "owl:cardinality"
      |   "rdf:datatype"="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger"
      |
      +---XText "0"




content of:

============


---XTag "rdf:Description"

 |   "rdf:about"="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#Camera"




content of:

============


---XTag "owl:Restriction"

   |

   +---XTag "owl:onProperty"

   |   |   "rdf:resource"="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#viewFinder"

   |

   +---XTag "owl:hasValue"

       |   "rdf:resource"="http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#ThroughTheLens"
```

Normally, after the second "content of" it should be a line with : ***************
But that line isn't appearing there !

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *it doesn't work* ? Do you get an error message?

Comment: i don't get any message from traceMsg ! But WithTraceLevel does work ! I get my tree prompt on my terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*withTraceLevel*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlState-TraceHandling.html#v%3awithTraceLevel) sets only the trace level for the arrow you give as its second parameter.

In your code below, *withTraceLevel* enables trace and sets the level during *traceTree* execution only, not the rest

```hs
withTraceLevel 5 traceTree >>> traceMsg 1 "bla bla"
```

try this instead

```
withTraceLevel 5 (traceTree >>> traceMsg 1 "bla bla")
```

See what happens in the interpreter:

```bsh
$ ghci
Prelude> :m +Text.XML.HXT.Core Text.XML.HXT.Arrow.XmlState.TraceHandling
Prelude ...> runX $ withTraceLevel 2 $ traceMsg 1 "hi!"
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading ...
-- (1) hi!
[NTree (XTag "/" []) []]
```

Comment: @Damiii Although you have accepted the answer it seems that you have not awarded the bounty scoring yet. It is still open.

Comment: I'm sorry ! I thought it will do automatically ! Did you get it ? :)

Comment: @Damiii I have received it. Thanks. If it's not directly awarded, the response need to have a minimum score of 2 to receive half of it at the end of the [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) period.